# Assign value to elements in array from Object properties and different Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey I would like to create a new array, from those two elements looking like this:

```
var a = {szerokosc: 42, wysokosc: 53, dlugosc: null}    // an object
var b = ['dlugosc', '*', 'szerokosc', '+', 'wysokosc']  // an array
```

The code must work if the correct name is found.
At the End I hope to receive an array like this one:

```
var c = ['0', '*', '42', '+', '53']
```

If anyone can tell me how to achieve this, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share what you have attempted till now.

Comment: Hint: `a[b[2]]` is 42. You should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `a[x]` to check the data, simply using `b.map(x => a[x] || x)` will return `[ 'dlugosc', '*', 42, '+', 53 ]` due to `dlugosc` having `null` value so you need to catch that by checking if the key is present in the object.

Steps:

1. If the key is present, check if `a[x]` has a value
2. If `a[x]` doesn't have any value, return `0` instead.
3. If `a[x]` has a value, return that.
4. Lastly, if the key isn't present in the object, return the same element

```js
var a = {szerokosc: 42, wysokosc: 53, dlugosc: null}    // an object
var b = ['dlugosc', '*', 'szerokosc', '+', 'wysokosc']  // an array

console.log(b.map(x => Object.keys(a).includes(x) ? !a[x] ? 0 : a[x] : x))
```

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```js
var a = {szerokosc: 42, wysokosc: 53, dlugosc: 0}    // an object
var b = ['dlugosc', '*', 'szerokosc', '+', 'wysokosc']  // an array

const transform = (data, dictonary) => data.map(i => dictonary.hasOwnProperty(i)? dictonary[i] : i)

console.log(transform(b, a))
```

Comment: That's also what I wanted! Thanks!